# Can "some couldn't know" be used to console somebody?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conversation

A : "Hey pal, I don't think I can go on anymore. I feel people around me are much greater than me. I feel I'm useless and nobody cares about me."
B : "Don't worry. It's okay. Some couldn't know." (= there are some who couldn't understand the true value of you)

Does it make sense? I guess it's fine since "how could they know" in Rebel Rebel by David Bowie has a similar meaning.

Comment: [Many] idioms and even some other fixed phrases are notoriously resistant to even slight changes in form. _Kick the bucket_ but not _kick the pail_. "You could have fooled me" but not "I could have been fooled by you". This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no. It doesn't sound natural to me. Google books confirms this suspicion: "some couldn't know" gets simply [no hits at all](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Some+couldn%27t+know%22).

Also, I don't see any subjunctives here, despite the fact that one of tags says 'subjunctive-mood'.

As far as the expanded sentence

[1] *There are some who couldn't understand the true value of you.*

it is a good English sentence.

However, [1] still doesn't address the fact that A feels that everyone is 'greater' than him or her (which is a weird thing to say, by the way... unless there is some reason why A would think that she herself is in fact great in some way—just far less so than everyone else around her).

Also, [1] doesn't address the fact that it's apparently not just some people who don't care about A, but basically everyone.

As far as what *would* be an appropriate thing to say to A, try [Interpersonal Skills StackExchange](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I just thought the root of A's problem is feeling inferiority, losing confidence and underestimating him/herself so saying [1] still makes sense. I was just trying to be able to say something clever in conversation but it looks like it's quite hard for a non-native English speaker. I'll try the link.

Comment: @dixhom Yes, the feeling of inferiority is the root problem. And the problem with [1] is that it is A herself who is the most relevant person who 'couldn't understand her true value'.  So you need to make her feel that she does matter, despite of what she may feel (as opposed to despite of what others may feel). See the three paragraphs beginning  [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=HnOyDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT45&dq=%22Affirming%20your%20worth%20is%20no%20easy%20task.%20Right%20now%22&pg=PT45#v=onepage&q=%22Affirming%20your%20worth%20is%20no%20easy%20task.%20Right%20now%22&f=false).

Comment: I read the paragraphs. I found the concepts and ideas stated in them quite different from ones in Japanese culture in which I grew up. I can imagine people would say "huh? why are you saying such idealistic things? See the reality!" if you mentioned them.  But I guess I can use them to people in Western culture since the book is highly rated on Amazon.com.

Comment: @dixhom Oh, these things will definitely strongly depend on the culture... Good luck!